# Selenium python socket buffer error 10055

Tags: python, sockets, selenium

Hello I have a selenium python script which checks a local webpage for a value.

After a few minuets i get a socket 10055 error (buffer space or queue was full).
I am guessing that I check the page too many times and it keeps those connections alive in the buffer and eventually run out of ports.

If I am correct in assuming its just an issue with not closing the connections, how do I go about closing the connections without stopping the code or the ChromeDriver that its using ?

Also I'm not entirely sure why its opening so many connections to cause this error. I only open the page once then check it for a Id and a Value, when there is a value it runs a script and only then does it ever interact with the page.
(This error happens when not interacting with the page)

If I am wrong what else could the problem be ? Code listed below.

```
import os
import sys
import time
import win32com.client
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities    
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://192.168.0.3:3333/")
while True:
    elem = driver.find_element_by_id('keyvalue')
    abc = elem.get_attribute("value")
    if abc != '':
        shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
        shell.Run("notepad++")
        shell.AppActivate("notepad++")
        time.sleep(0.1)
        shell.SendKeys(abc, 0)
        driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('keyvalue').value = ''")
```

Comment: `    if abc != '':
        print (abc)
    if abc != '':`

Comment: i duplicate code if its parts for testing the print (abc) is going to get removed so i keep it away from the other stuff. but thats not really the issue im looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's the connection to the web page that uses that many sockets but [Selenium Webdriver](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ScalingWebDriver) itself. This framework uses of a lot of ephemeral ports and leaves them in `TIME_WAIT` status. As you are calling `find_element_by_id` in a loop this might be your problem. At least you should move your `time.sleep` before the `if` check to give your TCP-ports a chance to get closed. You can your port states with `netstat -n` in the command line.

Comment: Thank you. have been running if for a few hours without a crash. is there a way to figure out which ports is opening ? i have been looking over the documentation but found little about sockets and ports.

Comment: I guess Selenium can use any port defined as ephemeral port: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port